# How to tell Dispatcher is initialized and running?

Tags: wpf, system.reactive, dispatcher

In my console app I've been trying to start an STA thread and show a `WPF` window. I've succeeded showing the window, but I had issues with a library using `Dispatcher` (`System.Reactive.Windows.Threading` to be precised). I've fixed my problems using code from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model#multiple-windows-multiple-threads) - what I was missing was calling `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()` in the right moment.

But after reading this article carefully (and others) and examining `Dispatcher's` API I still don't know: how to tell `WPF Dispatcher` is correctly initialized and running? It'd be very useful for libraries requiring `Dispatcher`, if they could check it.

-- EDIT --

// Extending my question after @Peter Duniho remarks

Having C# console application I wanted to create a WPF window, where I'll observe, on Dispatcher, some data. The full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/MaciekSwiszczowski/9ab3b1ffe173ca54cb0c9d73475f1be8)

So I have my program, where Main class looks like that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var observable = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .TakeWhile(counter => counter < 10);

        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            new TestWindow(observable);
            Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I create here an observable with Interval operator, which ticks every 500 milliseconds, and I pass it to a TestWindow (code below) which I run on a separate thread. After 10 ticks I end the observable sequence.

`TestWindow` class:

```
public class TestWindow : Window
    {
        public TestWindow(IObservable<long> observable)
        {
            var isDispatcherInitialized = false;

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => isDispatcherInitialized = true, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);

            if (!isDispatcherInitialized)
                throw new ApplicationException("Dispatcher not initialized");

            observable
                .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                .Window(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600))
                .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine($"OnNext, observed on dispatcher with Window operator"));
        }
    }
```

In TestWindow I observe my observable on Dispatcher (`ObserveOnDispatcher()`), and I use Window operator.

PROBLEM with that code (tested on .NET Framework and on .NET Core 3.0 preview):

- if I don't call `Dispatcher.Run();` when starting STA thread, the validation where I call `Dispatcher.Invoke()` will be passed, but `ObserveOnDispatcher()` won't work correctly - subscription never stops, and the message: "OnNext, observed on dispatcher with Window operator" goes forever.

That's why I was wondering if I could detect Dispatcher's state.

Comment: "*if I don't call Dispatcher.Run() ...*" is that your question? Why would you *not* call it?

Comment: I don't think it's obvious you need to call Dispatcher.Run(), as without calling it window.ShowDialog() will work, and WPF will work normally. Only some corner cases will not work, like in my example.

Comment: FWIW, `ShowDialog()` implicitly calls `Dispatcher.Run()`, and IMHO _that_ is the "corner case". The normal scenario for a WPF program is the program entry point calls `Dispatcher.Run()` explicitly. That said, it's still not entirely clear to me whether that's your question or something else is. Also, you've added details relating to your use of Rx; can you _only_ reproduce the issue when using Rx? If so, does that make your question more about Rx than about `Dispatcher`? If not, it would be better for you to post a simpler [mcve] that doesn't use Rx.

Comment: Beyond all that, some notes about the code you posted: the `Dispatcher` property creates a dispatcher on the current thread if none exists. This will interfere with your attempts to discover whether there is in fact a dispatcher. Also, the `Invoke()` method is going to protect you from yourself and invoke the delegate directly if you are calling it from the dispatcher's owning thread, which means it's not going to give you useful information about the state of the dispatcher. If on the owning thread, you will need to use one of the asynchronous methods for the priority to have any effect.

Comment: So far, the only thing that doesn't seem to work for you is that the code doesn't work if you don't call `Dispatcher.Run()`, and you seem to have figured that out already all on your own. I'm still not seeing what specific problem it is you want help with. As far as the code you posted goes, I wouldn't do it that way. That is, I'd run the dispatcher in the thread as you do, but I would do no initialization in the `Window` constructor, except to subscribe to the `Loaded` event, and do the initialization in that event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Peter Duniho, I see it's not my best day as for clearly explaining my questions. I was curious if I can detect the state of Dispatcher from the code that uses it, not having possibility to control how the thread was created. I've checked now your suggestion to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() and it does what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you would elaborate on this statement:

> It'd be very useful for libraries requiring `Dispatcher`, if they could check it.

That is, why would it be useful?

For one, if you are using a third-party library (such as the [Reactive Extensions (Rx) for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive.Windows.Threading/) you mentioned, how would you knowing how to check for the dispatcher state help that library?

For another, what scenario *doesn't work* for you? Lacking a specific problem to solve, your question is fairly open-ended. It's not clear what type of answer would actually address your question.

That said, two things come to mind:

1. If you want to know if a dispatcher has been *created* for a given thread, you should call `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread);` This will return `null` if not dispatcher has been created yet for that thread, or a reference to the dispatcher if it has been.
2. If you want to know that the dispatcher has completed initialization and is ready to dispatch things, it seems to me that the easiest thing to do is ask it to dispatch something, and when it does, it's ready. Using an overload of one of the invoking methods (`BeginInvoke()`, `Invoke()`, or `InvokeAsync()`) that takes a `DispatcherPriority` value, you can get fine-grained information regarding just what level of initialization has happened. For example, if you pass `DispatcherPriority.Normal` or `DispatcherPriority.Send`, when your delegate is invoked you'll know that the dispatcher is running. But if you pass `DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle` or `DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle`, you'll know that not only is the dispatcher running, but it's cleared its backlog of initial events to dispatch and the application is sitting waiting for user input.

Comment: Hi @Peter Duniho, thanks for answering my question. I've extended it to better explain what I need.